# Strange difference in bash behavior across systems

Tags: bash

I have two systems, an Ubuntu computer and an Android tablet.
I have built and configured bash for Android to be used in adb, so it's the same version as my Ubuntu bash, and they use mostly the same bashrc and configuration, and the same exact options set by shopt.

However, there is a slight difference in that the Android bash behaves as I expect when I I try to tab-complete something using a variable in it, but the Ubuntu bash doesn't.

```
 #Android
 ls $HOME/loc<tab> => ls $HOME/local #As expected
```

Basically, the variable is taken into account when completing. But then

```
#Ubuntu
ls $HOME/loc<tab> => ls \$HOME/loc #Undesired behavior.
```

The list of options is as follows, and is the same in both builds of bash.

```
autocd:checkwinsize:cmdhist:expand_aliases:extglob:extquote:force_fignore:histappend:interactive_comments:progcomp:promptvars:sourcepath
```

What can be making the Ubuntu version escape the $ instead of using it for completion as in the Android build? What can I do to make both work the same way? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What version of ubuntu / bash are you running?

Comment: Ubuntu 12.10, bash 4.2.37(1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bash package 4.2-0ubuntu3 exhibits this problem, as per this bug:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bash/+bug/778627/

Apparently this in an issue with bash itself, so right now, your option is to download and compile an upstream copy of bash to run on your machine.

Comment: Oh, I completely didn't think it'd be a distro bug, believe it or not. Easy fix then, I'll just build my own. Thanks for letting me know and providing the launchpad bug link!

Comment: I have built bash, but it still does the same thing...this must be a problem with something else.

Comment: The problem seems to be related to bash-completion. I am not sure of how to fix it, but doesn't look like a problem in bash itself.